# getting (400) Bad Request error in Update preview

Tags: 2013, siteedit

I m using sdl tridion 2013

the error is

Unable to update the changes using OData Service.

```
The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.

Component: Tridion.ContentManager.Publishing.PreviewService
Errorcode: 1003
User: NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE

StackTrace Information Details:
  at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
  at System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceContext.SaveResult.BatchRequest(Boolean replaceOnUpdate)
  at System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceContext.SaveChanges(SaveChangesOptions options)
  at Tridion.ContentManager.Publishing.PreviewService.ServiceImplementation.Preview(IEnumerable`1 publishedItemsInfo, TcmUri publishingTargetId)
  at Tridion.ContentManager.Publishing.PreviewService.ServiceImplementation.Preview(IEnumerable`1 publishedItemsInfo, TcmUri publishingTargetId)
  at SyncInvokePreview(Object , Object[] , Object[] )
  at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.SyncMethodInvoker.Invoke(Object instance, Object[] inputs, Object[]& outputs)
  at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc& rpc)
  at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage5(MessageRpc& rpc)
  at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage31(MessageRpc& rpc)
  at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean isOperationContextSet)
```

i comment out ambientdata httpmodule from system.webserver inside odataservice webconfig and preview website webconfig it was giving java error is this problem beacause of that??

in the trace file i m getting this error

Unable to cast object of type 'Com.Tridion.Webservices.Odata.Input.Handler.ODataResponse' to type 'Com.Tridion.Webservices.Odata.Input.Handler.ODataBatchResponse'.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11411315/tridion-ui-bad-request

Comment: Your question is very unclear, you only mention that you are unable to update "the" changes, and don't specify any details (like what version of SDL Tridion you use and what you were ding when this error appeared). I'll attempt to supply an answer, but you really should edit your question and provide more detail and context about your question before we can really help you.

Comment: i comment out ambienddata httpmodule from system.webserver it was giving java error is this problem beacause of that??

Comment: Getting the same with my XPM. I think essential is the last line ("Unable to cast..") Did folder-2-folder comparison against stock Preview webservice binaries and config and they look equivalent. So i suspect the problem is in incoming request(s). Now i wonder where to look next: TcmServiceHost, or elsewhere? PS: Here's a relevant excerpt from WCF trace: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/e0d0a80b26d2a2840ed6

Comment: What was solution to this problem? We are facing same problem. No error in log file or in odata service. But on clicking update preview it throws same error with same stack trace as in question above. Posting as answer as i am unable to add comment :-| Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't seen exactly this one, but something similar when my Session Preview Content Delivery Endpoint URL was misconfigured.

Reading the error description I would guess your endpoint URL (the Session Preview oData service) is up and running, but it might have some other issues. I would checkout if you can manually browse that oData service and if that looks okay perhaps check out its logfiles for more details.

On IIS this typically means an issue with the correct jars and DLLs, please check the following steps for that:

1. For the oData website, ensure DLLs are copied from the Installation folder `<Installation Media>\Content Delivery\roles\webservice\dotNET\webapp\x86_64.zip\bin` and jars are updated from `<Installation Media>\Content Delivery\roles\webservice\dotNET\webapp\x86_64.zip\bin`
2. For the oData website, verify if web.config `<service>` nodes **bindingConfiguration** attribute are correct
3. For Preview website, ensure DLLs are copied from the User Interface folder `<Installation Media>\Content Delivery\roles\web\dotNET\webapp\x86_64.zip\bin` and all jars are replaced with contents from the installation folder `<Installation media>\Content Delivery\roles\web\dotNET\webapp\x86_64.zip\bin\lib`

Comment: Thanks Bart i m using sdl tridion 2013 .the Session Preview oData service is up and running Log file is not helping i m only getting error in cms side   Component: Tridion.ContentManager.Publishing.PreviewService
Errorcode: 1003

Comment: @Abdul, please edit your question and provide that information in there (also tag it with [tag:2013]), so others can see it too and provide a more suitable answer perhaps